# How should a POCO be like?

Tags: c#, poco, dto

I've been trying to understand thease two for past 2 days I know that DTO is something like this

```
public class LineItem
{
    public Int32 SalesOrderID { get; set; }
    public Int32 SalesOrderDetailID { get; set; }
    public String CarrierTrackingNumber { get; set; }
    public Int16 OrderQty { get; set; }
    public Int32 ProductID { get; set; }
    public Int32 SpecialOfferID { get; set; 
}
```

But I have no idea about POCO,and I saw some Example, they use DTO and POCO really look like each other.
How we should write a poco? can it be a normal CRUAD class?

Comment: I don't believe there is any difference. it's different naming probably. POCO stands for `Plain Old Class Object` and thus what you have posted is a POCO

Comment: Plain Old CLR Object @Rahul

Comment: @dotctor, Nahh!!! refer wikipedia and see yourself.